# Erro de sintaxe no 'with' com SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenh o seguinte erro no sql server:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

O que pode ser?

Segue o código:

```
  declare @data date='2018-05-21'

  With SomaDebCred AS (
  SELECT ContabLancNumCtrl, 
   sum(case when ContabLancCtaCred is not null then ContabLancValor else 0 
  end) as soma_debito,
   sum(case when ContabLancCtaDeb is not null then ContabLancValor else 0 
  end) as soma_credito
  from CONTAB_LANCAMENTO
  where ContabLancData = @data
    and EmpCod='01.02'
  group by ContabLancNumCtrl

 ),
 NomeClientes AS (
 SELECT A.ContabLancNumCtrl, A.soma_debito, A.soma_credito,
   L.ContabLancValor, L.ContabLancHistComp,
   L.ContabLancCtaCred, L.ContabLancCtaDeb
 from SomaDebCred as A
   inner join CONTAB_LANCAMENTO as L on L.ContabLancNumCtrl = 
   A.ContabLancNumCtrl
   where A.soma_debito <> A.soma_credito

   )

  SELECT * FROM SomaDebCred
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM NomeClientes
```

Comment: "Sintaxe incorreta perto da palavra-chave "com". Se essa instrução for uma expressão de tabela comum, uma cláusula xmlnamespaces ou uma cláusula de contexto de controle de alterações, a instrução anterior deverá ser terminada com um ponto-e-vírgula"

Comment: coloca um ponto e virgula de pois de declare @data date='2018-05-21'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se usa `with`, é preciso usar ponto e vírgula após o comando anterior.

```
declare @data date='2018-05-21';
```

Comment: Agora deu outro erro que não sei tbm resolver: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: Quando vc usa UNION, as querys devem retornar obrigatoriamente o mesmo número de colunas.

Comment: Já deu certo aqui, não precisa mais!